# Close first PR since derived branch has that changes too

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have worked on `task1` branch and after that, I have pushed it and then create a pull request. No merge conflicts with the `master`.

Since the above PR has not been merged to the `master` I have created a 2nd branch as `task2` using `task1` branch like so:

```
git checkout -b task2 task1
```

After that, I have pushed that branch like so:

```
git push --set-upstream origin task2
```

There are no merge conflicts on that branch too. So my question is do I need `task1` branch `PR` now? Since I have derived `task2` branch from `task1` hope I can `close` the `task1`'s `PR` no? Will I have to face any issues?

Comment: It depends what your objective is.  If you close the original PR and create a new PR from `task2`, it will contain the union of *all* the changes.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, exactly that is what I need. I need all the work of `task1` and `task2` branches and merge it into the `master` at the end. Will that workflow has any side effects? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: If other developers have already reviewed your original PR (and added comments etc.) then I suppose they might be annoyed that they have to do that again!  And in certain teams, large multi-feature PRs are discouraged.  But I think these are ultimately "cultural" concerns, rather than technical ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great info. @OliverCharlesworth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the original PR and create a new PR from task 2, it will contain the combination of all changes. There won't be any effects other than that to your workflow.